# How to create a managed plugin for Unity with Visual Studio Community for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm going to create my first **managed plugin** for Unity (2018.2) using Visual Studio Community for Mac (7.6.11 build 9).

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/Manual/UsingDLL.html) but I think that the step-by-step instructions are not meant to be followed on Visual Studio Community for Mac.

As you can see in the screenshot below, I've created several projects using each and every library template available.

[image: New Project]

All of them compiled successfully to a DLL targeting versions of .NET framework that are incompatible with Unity.

[image: Unity Inspector]

The only project I could change the .NET framework version to match Unity's 3.5 is the one based on the **Other > .NET > Library**.

[image: Project Options]

**Everything works fine but I'd like to know if the assumptions, the process and the final result are correct. Can you tell me, please?**

Comment: Hi @Adriano Di Giovanni, I have the same problem while import DLL file in unity project. have you found any solution?

Comment: You can follow the steps I outline in my question. The assumptions I wanted to verify by asking here are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the difference between the "Class" and the "Class Library" option but you're supposed to use the "Class Library" option. This is not the main point of this answer.

Two future issues you haven't solved yet:

**1**. Referencing Unity's API.

If you ever have to use any Unity library or API in youir plugin such as `Vector3`, you need to add Unity's `UnityEngine.dll` to your library settings. If you don't, you will run-time exceptions.

Go to Project --> Add Reference ---> Browse ---> Browse Button
then select `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll`. You can now build your managed plugin. Since you're using Mac, this path is different on your OS. On Mac, this could be `/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Managed/UnityEngine.dll`. You just have to find where `UnityEngine.dll` is located.

**2**. Invisible stack trace

With your current setup, if you run into error with your managed plugin, the stack trace won't be there. You won't have the  file names and line numbers and this makes is very hard to debug your plugin code.

When you build the project, Visual Studio generates a PDB file instead of an MDB file. Unity can't use this directly. You have to convert the PDB files into MDB files.

From command line, run this:

```
<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5\pdb2mdb.exe UnmanagedPlugin.dll
```

Again, the path might be different on Mac, you just need to find "pdb2mdb.exe" that converts the PDB files into MDB files.

After that, copy the MDB and dll file into the "Assets" folder in your Unity project.

Comment: I am trying to convert the PDB files into MDB files according to your answer I got below output. 


imac$  pdb2mdb TestWaterMark.dll
Mono pdb to mdb debug symbol store converter
Usage: pdb2mdb assembly